# the html code generated by Struts2

Tags: html, internationalization, struts2, cjk

My web application is built with Struts2 on Geronimo 2.2.1.
The content of my web is Chinese. The below is just a portion of my web page.

```
<div id="tabs" class="hot_topic">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">重點新聞</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">保廠優惠</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">推薦文</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    Rolls-Royce &#21488;&#21271;&#25480;&#27402;&#32147;&#37559;&#21830;&#32173;&#20462;&#20013;&#24515;&#27491;&#24335;&#25237;&#20837;&#36939;&#29151;<br/>
                        &#20572;&#36554;&#36229;&#36942;15&#31186;&#20197;&#19978;&#65292;&#35531;&#23559;&#27284;&#20301;&#25490;&#22238;&#31354;&#27284;<br/>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
     <p>OO保養廠提供3000優惠</p>
  </div>
     <div id="tabs-3">
        昨天在OO 汽車安裝引擎室拉桿，老闆送我星星樂園門票
  </div>
 </div>
```

The content in

```
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
```

are generated by Struts2. As you can see, the format of the content looks like uni-format or whatever I don't know. and other Chinese words are static text.

The code used to generated the content in (id="tabs-1") is below:

```
<s:iterator value="#request.importantNews" var="article">                           
  <s:property value="#article.subject"/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

I tried to make the Chinese words generated by Struts2 in html code look like the static text so I added the below properties into struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.locale" value="zh_TW" />
<constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

I also have the below lines in my web page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

However, all the above methods are in vain.
I believe that there is no relation to Geronimo because if I use JSTL to display the variable ${article.subject} then the Chinese words in html code looks normal.

My problem is, how do I make the Chinese words generated by Struts2 in html code looks just like static Chinese words?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: a quick test what if you use <s:textfield name="abc" value="#article.subject"/>still the problem is there??

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, thank you for your suggestion. I tried it. Although the display result in browser is correct, the words in html code are still in the format like &#21488;&#21271;&#25480; .

However, a friend gave me a way to solve it. When using <s:property />, add an attribute escapeHtml="false" will solve the problem. Although I don't think this is a long-way solution, it works.

Comment: yup that is one of the way and strts2 property tag work in some weired way, my suggestion is if possible go for JSTL tag